# Trace on homology (proof of the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem)

Tags: algebraic-topology

Assume that $C_i$ are **finitely generated free abelian groups** and $C=\{ (C_i,d_i)\}$ is a chain
 complex s.t. $C_i=0$ except finitely many $i$.

If $g_i: C_i\rightarrow C_i$ is group homomorphism s.t. $$d_i g_i=
g_{i-1} d_i,$$ then we have $G_n:H_n(C)\rightarrow H_n(C)$.

Here show that $$ \sum_n(-1)^n\ {\rm tr}\ g_n = \sum_n (-1)^n\ {\rm
tr}\ G_n\ \ast
$$

How can we prove this ? Thank in advance.

Note : This is in the proof of the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem. I can prove the Euler characteristic Theorem, i.e., $\chi (X)=\sum_n(-1)^n\cdot {\rm rank}\ H^n(X)$, whose proof contains a similar argument for $\ast$. But I can not derive that.